# Phpmailer returns blank page without sending email

Tags: php, email, outlook

I develop a PHP system that need to send an email to the user. I need to use Outlook account to send the email and I'm using PHPmailer.

FYI, my SMTP is valid because I get it from my company IT department.

This is what I changed in both php.ini(Apache & PHP) :
    [mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/smtp
    SMTP = abc-smtp.mycompany.local
    ; http://php.net/smtp-port
    smtp_port = 25

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = abc@mycompany.com
```

It failed when I try to send the email. There is no output showing error include telling the message has been sent or message was not sent.

I tried to do some changes include : 
1) change the port to 465, but it gives error saying :-

```
fsockopen() [<a href='function.fsockopen'>function.fsockopen</a>]: SSL: crypto
enabling timeout in C:\wamp\www\assetmanagementsystem\class.smtp.php on line 122
```

2) Uncomment extension=php_openssl.dll. 
3) Grant my IP address in the SMTP server.

Does anybody know what should I do to allow the outlook send my email ? Please help me. I really dont know what to do now. This is my coding for sending the mail .

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail  = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->SMTPSecure = "";                
$mail->Host       = 'abc-smtp.mycompany.local';      
$mail->Port       = 25;                   
$mail->Username   = "";   
$mail->Password   = "";            

$mail->From       = "abc@mycompany.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Asset Management System";
$mail->Subject    = "Notification on less of stock";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

$mail->AddAddress("abc@mycompany.com","Asset Management System");
$mail->IsHTML(true); 

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
```

Comment: Set the Charset and specify the IP of the Host. I had the same problem when i used the name, then i entered the IP and everything worked

Comment: "FYI, my SMTP is valid because I get it from my company IT department." -> Not clever to assume everything as correct that comes from an IT department

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that @YUNOWORK? Where to set the charset and the IP. I'm afraid I did it at a wrong place.

Comment: Ill post my code below, this works for sure, just censored a little bit. You can take the necessary parts out of it.

Comment: I'm sure the SMTP is valid because my company is using the same SMTP to trigger email for another system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->SMTPdebug = true;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = '10.xxx.xxx.xxx';
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->IsHTML(false);

    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, "Vertragsverwaltung");

    $mail->SetFrom('vertragsverwaltung@domain.de', 'Vertragsverwaltung');

    $address = $email;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

    $mail->Subject = "This is my subject";

    $mail->Body = "Text: \n\r" . $message;

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "[" . date("d.m.Y H:i", time()) . "] Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "[" . date("d.m.Y H:i", time()) . "] Message sent!";
    }
```

Not enough text, blablablablablablablablasdjkflasjdflöasdjflaösdjfalösdjf

Comment: I've tried this, but it is not working for me :( Do you have any method to overcome this problem ?